# Symfony2: how to choose Javascript files load order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I am using jQuery in my Symfony2 application and I have a "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" error. I think changing Javascript file load order could fix this.

How could I force to load jQuery Javascript file first in order to avoid such errors? I would like to keep the "js/*" in order to load auto-magically the future new JS files I will put.

Here is stylesheets part of my *.html.twig template:

```
    {% javascripts
            '@xxxBundle/Resources/public/js/*'
            'js/*'
        %}
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
```

And here is current output generated by Symfony2:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/js/8d3a8ee_part_2_acidTabs_1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/js/8d3a8ee_part_2_jquery-1.6.min_2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can list your core dependencies first, then load all others:

```
{% javascripts
        '@xxxBundle/Resources/public/js/*'
        'js/example_1.js'
        'js/example_2.js'
        ...
        'js/*' %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Comment: What about if example_1.js is in the same directory as * ?